# How can we bring currencies to record level

Tags: salesforce

Can you please explain how can we bring the manage currencies to record level. It was changing daily so can you please explain how it was being changed and how is it used in record level.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly worded. An opportunity that's worth €1000 and nobody edits it will still be worth  €1000 tomorrow. What can change daily is currency **exchange rate** to $, £...

You can [enable currency management](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=admin_currency.htm&type=5&language=en_US) (if not done already) which causes `CurrencyIsoCode` picklist to appear in every table. And then -if you really need to keep info what the price was at specific point in time - you can add support for "[dated currency rates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5)" on top of that. There are some considerations that out of the box the exchange rate recalculates only on Opportunity & related object. For your custom objects you'll need to write a nightly (hourly?) batch for example.

Once you're sure that dated rates is what you need (because maybe you need just the basic version with 1 current exchange rate) look into an integration that would periodically contact some currency exchange info server and write to either [CurrencyType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) or [DatedConversionRate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm)